# A question to the Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

How do i prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb C \setminus\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb C $ so that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ that is not the constant nullfunction.

Why is that not a contradiction to the Identity theorem?

Comment: With regard to your latter question, do you see a difference between having a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C-\{0\}$ and having an entire function?

Comment: If the function would be entire i could use Liouville´s theorem. Since f would have roots this would imply that f isnt a constant function especially not the constant nullfunction

Comment: No, you're not understanding. You have no idea whether the function is bounded. But when $0$ is in the domain, the identity theorem now applies!

Comment: Indeed i misread the assumptions of Liouville´s theorem. Thank you aswell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to construct an example.  For example,
$$
f(z) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)
$$
This does not contradict the identity theorem because $f$ and the null-function agree only on $\{1/n:n \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}\}$, which is not an open set (nor does it contain an open set).  That is, $\{f = 0\}$ has an empty interior.

Comment: Got it! Thanks alot